# Editing CSV file in Centos command line

Tags: linux, csv, centos

Hi I have a complex CSV file, I would like to be able to open/edit this file so it fits an ELFF format,

im new to Centos / Linux in general. is there a way to open my CSV file so I can edit it to fit the ELFF format from the command line? or an application I can install todo this?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Probably, but your question is probably a bit too broad for Stack Overflow - we're looking at solutions to coding problems. If you had made a start at parsing it, and had your own sample input/output, that might be a better fit.

Comment: Ah fair enough, tbh i'm not looking for a coding solution here, but a premade solution / command in Linux - this may not be the right place to post this question

Comment: Unix/Linux StackExchange or SuperUser might be. But check if product recommendations are on topic there first.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a bit of an idiot, I just used vi (I know this isn't really the place for this question) but just incase anyone else wanted to know the answer.